# Como eu acesso uma ArrayList de Fragments depois de uma rotação de tela?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, nullpointerexception

Eu estava tentando adicionar programaticamente à minha Activity uma lista de Fragments que implementam alguns CardViews. Estes CardViews têm algumas TextViews que eu gostaria de definir a partir de minha Activity, e de fato, funciona definindo-as em eventos após onCreateView do Fragment, como onStart e onResume. Ou melhor, não... É melhor dizer, quase funciona. Quando há uma rotação de tela (e tudo o que forçaria o reinício de uma Activity), tentar fazer alguma coisa com qualquer Fragment, mesmo nos métodos onStart e onRestart, resulta em um NullPointerException. Basicamente eu tenho:

**MyActivity.java**

```
private List<MyFragment> cards = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rucardapio); 

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        /* Here I create 10 fragment cards */
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cards.add(new MyFragment());
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, cards.get(i));
        }

        transaction.commit();

   }

}
```

Depois de alguns testes, supus que o problema está no `if (savedInstanceState != null) { return; }`. Tentei essas "soluções" que não me ajudaram:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389938/nullpointerexception-when-accessing-a-fragments-textview-in-an-activity , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748277/npe-thrown-when-trying-to-find-button-id-in-android-fragment , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534804/how-would-i-implement-a-generic-arraylist-of-fragments-in-android e muito mais...

---

Logcat:

```
01-24 09:07:21.848  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 43
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
01-24 09:07:21.888  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 48
01-24 09:07:40.088  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu, PID: 30751
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu.ru.MyActivity$2.run(MyActivity.java:161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Código que funciona na inicialização do aplicativo mas não após uma mudança de configuração:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((TextView) cards.get(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como nenhuma resposta me ajudou, digo minha solução: consegui contornar os problemas criando um Fragment só para armazenar dados, conforme esta "receita de bolo" da própria documentação http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html, (que usa setRetainInstance(true) para não perder as instancias dos objetos declarados dentro do Fragment), e usando o Bundle salvo pela Activity. Preferi não mexer no .xml porque com isso eu teria que manipular eu mesmo certos eventos.

Com um condicional padrão eu verifico se a Activity está sendo recriada. Se estiver eu procuro o Fragment de dados e pego os objetos não modificados.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, entenda... Se o dispositivo é girado a atividade será destruída e recriada. Assim, o contexto em que você passou para os seus pontos Fragmento sobre a atividade foram destruídos. O que fazer?

Você poderia usar `setRetainInstance(true)` no seu Fragmento. Desta forma o seu Fragmento vai sobreviver a recriação da Atividade  :)

Para resolver o `NPE` você tem que passar o `Context` no `Fragment`, se a atividade for recriada. Em seguida, o Context pertencerá à nova atividade.

Resumindo, sem essa atualização a cada linha de código, que aponta sobre a atividade como getActivity() ou getFragmentManager(), vai levar em uma `NPE`.

Se você não quiser utilizar o processo normal de `destruir-e-recriar`, você pode usar o android: `configChanges attributes` em `AndroidManifest.xml.`

**EXEMPLO:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".SmsPopupActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:taskAffinity="net.everythingandroid.smspopup.popup">
</activity>
```

Desta forma, não será fechado quando girar, porque onCreate() `não é chamado`.

---

**Fontes:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867184/android-nullpointerexception-in-dialog-when-rotating

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29

**Estude:**

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/0/page/5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: Esta é uma resposta correta e o @Matheus RETIROU COMO CORRETA por motivos fúteis.